# Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

After some Google i found following code that can help to convert data row to specifics class

```
public static void SetItemFromRow(T item, DataRow row) where T : new()
{
    // go through each column
    foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
    {
        // find the property for the column
        PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName);

        // if exists, set the value
        if (p != null && row[c] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            p.SetValue(item, row[c], null);
        }
    }
}

// function that creates an object from the given data row
public static T CreateItemFromRow(DataRow row) where T : new()
{
    // create a new object
    T item = new T();

    // set the item
    SetItemFromRow(item, row);

    // return 
    return item;
}

public static List CreateListFromTable(DataTable tbl) where T : new()
{
    // define return list
    List lst = new List();

    // go through each row
    foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
    {
        // add to the list
        lst.Add(CreateItemFromRow(r));
    }

    // return the list
    return lst;
}
```

But both of them are giving me this error "**Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declaration**" I have Google a lot but no help regarding my function

The main thing i want is to make genric function that convert data table to list of class
 & data row to class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `<T>`

```
        public static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row)
        where T : new()
    {
        // go through each column
        foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            // find the property for the column
            PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName);

            // if exists, set the value
            if (p != null && row[c] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                p.SetValue(item, row[c], null);
            }
        }
    }
```